# How to modify the data of a unknown column name C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, datatable

I'm working on a script to Conversion some values from a file. I have a DataTable where I stored the column names and the rows but some  column names are different according to the file I imported, I have to convert many files with differents column names.

Example: ExcelA have this column

| ColumnA | C20200301 |
| --- | --- |
| 2.9 | 2.9 |

And ExcelB have almost the same columns but the difference is his datetime stamp

| ColumnA | C20210301 |
| --- | --- |
| 3.0 | 3.5 |

What I need is update of the values of that second column that start with a "C" and his datetime fixed from the original file.
So with that column name I need to convert the rows from a mm to a cm (not so difficult)

```
foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{
 row["ColumnA"] = (Convert.ToSingle(row["ColumnA"]) / 10).ToString("0.00");
}
```

This is the code that I normally use to Convert from an X value to a Y value.
Any ideas? I try with dictionaries, lists.

Comment: You can iterate the columns of the datatable and look for the proper name that matches your use case and store the name or index.

Comment: If the column index is consistent then use the index instead of the column name.

Comment: Thanks  @RyanWilson you give me the best Idea, I iterate the datatable and now is working thanks for your help